# Extracting coefficients from GLM in Python using statsmodel

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a model which is defined as follows:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
model = smf.glm(formula="A ~ B + C + D", data=data, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
```

The model has coefficients which look like so:

```
Intercept   0.319813
C[T.foo]   -1.058058
C[T.bar]   -0.749859
D[T.foo]    0.217136
D[T.bar]    0.404791
B           0.262614
```

I can grab the values of the `Intercept` and `B` by doing `model.params.Intercept` and `model.params.B` but I can't get the values of each `C` and `D`.

I have tried `model.params.C[T.foo]` for example, and I get and error.

How would I get particular values from the model?

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388258/how-to-extract-the-regression-coefficient-from-statsmodels-api

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`model.params` is is a pandas.Series. Accessing as attribute is only possible if the name of the entry is a valid python name.

In this case you need to index with the name in quotes, i.e. `model.params["C[T.foo]"]`

see
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html