# How to extract the regression coefficient from statsmodels.api?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

```
 result = sm.OLS(gold_lookback, silver_lookback ).fit()
```

After I get the result, how can I get the coefficient and the constant?

In other words, if
`y = ax + c`
how to get the values `a` and `c`?

Comment: For accessing coefficients individually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165601/extracting-coefficients-from-glm-in-python-using-statsmodel

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the `params` property of a fitted model to get the coefficients.

For example, the following code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
X = sm.add_constant(np.arange(100))
y = np.dot(X, [1,2]) + np.random.normal(size=100)
result = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(result.params)
```

will print you a numpy array `[ 0.89516052  2.00334187]` - estimates of intercept and slope respectively.

If you want more information, you can use the object `result.summary()` that contains 3 detailed tables with model description.

Comment: the first one is constant and the second one is the coefficient?

Comment: Exactly!
That's how ```sm.add_constant()``` works: it takes a matrix (or a vector, as in my case```, and adds the leftmost column of ones to it. The coefficient corresponding to this column is the intercept.

Answer (score 11):

Cribbing from this answer [Converting statsmodels summary object to Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734180/converting-statsmodels-summary-object-to-pandas-dataframe/52976810), it seems that the result.summary() is a set of tables, which you can export as html and then use Pandas to convert to a dataframe, which will allow you to directly index the values you want.

So, for your case (putting the answer from the above link into one line):

```
df = pd.read_html(result.summary().tables[1].as_html(),header=0,index_col=0)[0]
```

And then

```
a=df['coef'].values[1]
c=df['coef'].values[0]
```

Comment: Great! However, that does not work with summary2() whose details are more detailed!

Answer (score 2):

Adding up details on @IdiotTom answer.

You may use:

```
head = pd.read_html(res.summary2().as_html())[0]
body = pd.read_html(res.summary2().as_html())[1]
```

Not as nice, but the info is there.

Answer (score 0):

If the input to the API is `pandas` objects (i.e. a `pd.DataFrame` for the data, or `pd.Series` for x and for y), then when you access `.params` it will be a `pd.Series`, so each coefficient is easily accessible by its name.

For example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
# sm.__version__ is '0.13.1'


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0,  1,2,3,4],
                   'y': [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8]
                  })

sm.OLS.from_formula(formula='y~x-1', data=df).fit().params
```

Outputs the following `pd.Series`:

```
x    0.196667
dtype: float64
```

Allowing for an intercept term (by changing the formula from `y~x-1` to `y~x`) changes the output to include the intercept under the name `Intercept`:

```
Intercept    0.08
x            0.17
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients are saved as a dictionary in the `result.params` data frame, that's a pandas `Series`. In it, the constant term is stored as `Intercept`, as others pointed. The variable terms are stored with their variable names. So, if your model is `y ~ x`, the regression coefficients will be available as `result.params['Intercept']` (that's `b`) and `result.params['x']` (that's `a`) for the equation `y = a*x + b`.